# UV/Texture pixels crossed by Seam edge are not painted as expected

Tags: blender, blender-2.76

Unwrapped object was filled out with gradient color. As illustrated in below image, some pixels in UV/Texture view on Seamed edges boundaries are not filled with expected color. It looks like edge has to cross more than a half of the pixel to be colorized.

Is there a way to force all pixels crossed by Seam edge to be colorized properly?

[image: Texture Paint mode with UV/Image editor view]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Navigate to Texture Paint for given object and open Options, modify Bleed property, which defines how many pixels will be colorized in UV texture outside Seamed edges. Default is 2px.